# Handling exception occured inside Task.ContiueWith

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I am working on wpf and i have written the below code to display exception when they occured while fetching data from web service.

Two action methods are there, 1st is to call remote service and second to update UI object when it got the result.

I am getting exception box properly when exception occured during First action(intial), but when exception occurred in second action(success) they are ignored and nothing happed. Event breakpoint doesn't hit at last line of continue with .

I like to know what is happening and best possible solution. Can't this type of exception handled globally?

```
private void ExecuteSafely(string message, Action intial, Action successAction)
{

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(intial);
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.Exception != null)
        {
            HandleException(t.Exception);
        }
        else
        {
            successAction.Invoke();
        }
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: You mean an exception occurs inside `successAction.Invoke`?

Comment: Yes, inside successAction.Invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when exception occurred in second action(success) they are ignored
>   and nothing happens

Because you aren't wrapping your code in a `try-catch` block, hence the exception isn't handled and is swallowed by your continuation task.

To catch it, do the wrapping:

```
private void ExecuteSafely(string message, Action initial, Action successAction)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(initial).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.Exception != null)
        {
            HandleException(t.Exception);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
               successAction();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                // Handle your exception.
            }
        }
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

If you're using .NET 4.0, the exception swallowed will eventually be thrown during the finalization of the `Task`.

If you're using using .NET 4.5, `async-await` will be less verbose:

```
private async Task ExecuteSafelyAsync(string message, 
                                      Action initial, 
                                      Action successAction)
{
    try
    {
        var task = await Task.Run(initial);
        successAction();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // You get here if either Task.Run or successAction throws
    }
}
```

And when you invoke it:

```
await ExecuteSafelyAsync("hello", initial, success);
```

Comment: Thanks that's cool, Is there any way to to bubble up without usign try catch ? I am also wondering why "
            Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;" not handled that.

Comment: @Max_dev You'll need to monitor the returned task. Which framework version are you using?

Comment: .Net 4.5. Monitor !! How to do that ? By debugger i couldn't trace anything after exception

Comment: Thanks mate, both the solution seems to fix my current issue. but still i don't know why there are not handled DispatcherUnhandledException since they occured at UI Thread.

Comment: @Max_dev Because they're encapsulated *inside* the `Task`. If you want, you can register to the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event to observe any unhandled task exceptions.

Comment: I registered TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException , but they didn't called. Looks like they will be called only on dispose of Task

Comment: They didn't get called because the event is raised only when your `Task` is finalized.

Answer (score 0):

When successAction throw a Exception, UI thread can not catch Exception because of successAction was not be invoke on UI thread.

If you working on .net 4.5, I think you should use async/await, like:

```
private async void ExecuteSafely(string message, Action intial, Action successAction)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(intial);
        successAction.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: *UI thread can not catch Exception because of successAction was not be invoke on UI thread.* That's incorrect, `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` will invoke it on the UI thread, assuming that's where he's executing `ExecuteSafely` from.

Comment: I am executing the successAction on UI Thread(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())